# How to create a new partition with Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, disk-partitioning

When I run this on the command line it works fine:

```
 echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

But in Ansible it does not want to run in shell:

```
 - name: partition new disk
   shell: echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

It does not come back with an error, but it does not create the partition either.

I checked that Ansible and LVM will not do what I need.

Any advice?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

With Ansible 2.3 and above, you can use [`parted` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/parted_module.html) to create partitions from a block device.
For example:

```
 - parted:
     device: /dev/sdb
     number: 1
     flags: [ lvm ]
     state: present
```

To format the partition just use [`filesystem` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filesystem_module.html) as shown below:

```
 - filesystem:
     fstype: ext2
     dev: /dev/sdb1
```

To mount the partition to, let's say, `/work` folder just use [`mount` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html) as shown below:

```
- mount:
    fstype: ext2
    src: /dev/sdb1
    path: /work
    state: mounted
```

Answer (score 12):

By default, Ansible executes `/bin/sh` shell.
For example, if `/bin/sh` is linked to `dash`, it's built `echo` is different to the one in `bash` or GNU `echo`; so you end up with `-e` characters fed into fdisk.

Try:

```
- name: partition new disk
  shell: echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Or:

```
- name: partition new disk
  shell: /bin/echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 12):

**How to allocate all free space to a new partition and add it to LVM in Ansible**

- **If you're using LVM, look into this!**
- **If you want to use all the free space of the device, look into this!**

Starting with a device `/dev/sda` and an existing partition on `/dev/sda1` in `{{ volumeGroup }}`.

Use the following approach to create a partition `/dev/sda2` in the free space of `/dev/sda` and to subsequently add the new partition to the existing `{{ volumeGroup }}`

```
- name: "Create partitions on devices"    
  block:   
    - name: install parted
      package:
        name: parted
        state: present 
        
    - name: "Read device information /dev/sda"
      parted: 
        device: "/dev/sda"
        unit: MiB
      register: device_info
    
    - name: "Add new partition /dev/sda2"
      parted: 
        device: "/dev/sda"
        number: "2"
        part_type: primary
        flags: [ lvm ]
        state: present
        part_end: "100%"
        part_start: "{{ device_info.partitions[0].end + 1}}MiB" 
        
    - name: "Add device to exising volume group {{ volumeGroup }}."
      lvg:
        vg: "{{ volumeGroup }}"
        pvs: "/dev/sda1,/dev/sda2"
```

Answer (score 3):

With Ansible 2.12.5, tested and worked

```yaml
---
# tasks file for formatting /dev/sdb for Longhorn
- name: Add disk to longhorn
  hosts: longhorn_disk
  become: true
  tasks:
    - parted:
        device: /dev/sdb
        number: 1
        state: present
       
    - filesystem:
        fstype: ext4
        dev: /dev/sdb1
       
    - mount:
        fstype: ext4
        src: /dev/sdb1
        path: /mnt/sdb1
        state: mounted
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system helps double "n"

`echo -e "\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw" | fdisk /dev/sdb`